# Notifications not going away

Tags: temple-run-2

I've updated the game multiple times - I just recently switch my game to a new phone and Temple Run 2 keeps telling me I have artifacts I have yet to collect coins for. However I've already collected them but the notifications won't go away. [image: here it's showing unclaimed items][image: but here clearly shows they've been claimed??]